# Start and stop UISlider animation in Swift?

Tags: animation, uiview, uislider

The question is simple - how to start and stop animation for `UISlider` programmatically?

```
func playSliderAnimation() {
    view.slider.value = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
        self.view.slider.setValue(1, animated: true)
    }
}

func stopSliderAnimation() {
    view.slider.value = 0
}
```

tried a lot of combinations for `stopSliderAnimation` - animating, without of animation, small animation duration, dispath into main queue - nothing works. The  circle jumps left somewhere outside the bounds